# Deleting multiple backed up photos

Tags: backup

I am trying to un back up my photos from my Gmail account.  There are many and it would take a long time to go into each one and click on the trash icon. How can I select multiple photos to be sent to trash?  Every time I click an image it opens up and doesn't give me the option to delete lots at once by using SHIFT.  How do I send lots of photos to trash in one go?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Photos app, long-press on a photo. That would put a checkmark on that photo. Now single tap on as many photos as you want to select them. Afterwards, tap on the trash icon to delete them altogether.